# Visual Studio 2017 debugging error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I've been having trouble debugging for a long time. I installed **Productivity Power Tools 2017** 2 days ago. When I try to debug after I do not load it, I get the error "the breakpoint will not currently be hit".

[image]

When I make a Symbol Load after this error, I get a breakpoint, but this time I do **F10** and then it fires somewhere else or finishes the flow.

[image]

I do not know if this is related to **Productivity Power Tools 2017** but I have not made any changes.Now I have removed this extention, but the problem continues.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Running the project in debug mode? Cleaned and rebuilt?

Comment: @john release mode. I have completely focused on the plugin and not checked it out. Thank you. I change mode Debug solve it